# R: generate many number sequences in one call

Tags: r, do.call

I have 2 vectors of integer values.

```
> starts = 1:10
> ends = seq(1,100,10)
> ends
 [1]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
```

I'd like to generate sequences of numbers from starts to ends, so as to have 10 sequences from 1 to 1, 2 to 11, 3 to 21, etc.

I could easily do it with a for() loop, by I thought there would be something more elegant and faster. `do.call()` does not appear to do it since it complains:

```
> x = do.call(seq,list(from=starts,to=ends,by=1))
Error in seq.default(from = 1:10, to = c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71,  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Map`

```
 Map(`:`, starts, ends)
```

It will generate sequence for corresponding elements of 'starts', 'ends' in a `list`.

Or instead of `:`, we can use `seq` (as @MrFlick mentioned)

```
 Map(seq, starts, ends)
```

Comment: Or equivalently `Map(seq, starts, ends)`